# onPause() and onStop() of Activity lifecycle methods not being called

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have a single `Activity` and one `Service`. The activity is used for search and the service is used to display a hovering widget over all the screens like Facebook chat head does.

When the user leaves the activity like pressing back key I start a service and the widget starts hovering. On Clicking the hovering widget the activity is again relaunched from service by using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. But doing this when my activity is overlapped by other app activity neither `onStop()` nor `onPause()` is getting called. `onStop()` is called when the activity on top of it `onStop()` is called.

Can someone explain why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Activity Code:

```
public class CouponSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = CouponSearchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION_ACTIVITY_STARTED = 

"activity_created";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION_ACTIVITY_STOPPED = "activity_stopped";

public static void startActivity(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CouponSearchActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void startActivityFromService(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CouponSearchActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TAG",": onCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_coupon_search);
    CouponWidgetService.stopService(this);
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        initCouponSearchFragment();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d("TAG",": onNewIntent()");
}

private void initCouponSearchFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, CouponSearchFragment.newInstance()).commit();
}

private void sendBroadcast(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_ACTIVITY_STARTED);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("Broadcast sent", action = " +BROADCAST_ACTION_ACTIVITY_STARTED);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("TAG","onResume()");
    sendBroadcast();
    CouponWidgetService.stopService(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("TAG + "onPause()");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_ACTIVITY_STOPPED);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d("TAG", "onStop()");
    Log.d("Broadcast sent", action = " + BROADCAST_ACTION_ACTIVITY_STOPPED);
    CouponWidgetService.startService(this, StoreCoupons.getStoreCouponsResponse(), StoreCoupons.getSelectedCategories());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("onBackPressed()");
    //CouponWidgetService.startService(this, StoreCoupons.getStoreCouponsResponse(), StoreCoupons.getSelectedCategories());
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: How do you know onStop() and onPause() are not being called? Are you logging these methods?

Comment: @barq Yes exactly. But when the activity on top of it is stopped then onStop() of my activity is called.

Comment: onPause() will be called when your activity go into background. Perhaps you could show your code for more info of it was written?

Answer (score 0):

> But doing this when my activity is overlapped by other app activity
>   neither onStop() nor onPause() is getting called.

This looks like a legit behavior to me. When your `Activity` is overlapped by some other `Activity`, `onPause` will be called. If the "overlap" is complete (i.e. your `Activity` is no longer visible), then its `onStop` should also be called.

At some later time, when you click on "hovering widget", your `Activity` is already paused (and, potentially, stopped), therefore it won't get those lifecycle callbacks again.